# Request on advice on setting the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssid

I'd like to request an educated advice on how to proceed to create my network.

There are 4 apartments in the same multi-storey building. There is approx. 25 people living in the apartments. There is a central point in the basement, wherefrom there is an ethernet cable to each apartment. The apartments do not have inner wired network, but within the apartment connections are to be handled wirelessly. I will buy one internet connection, which will be used by all the apartments.

Questions:

- is one 100 Mpbs (theoretical, concrete speeds 50-100) enough for 25 people or should I get two connections (and also split the network into two)?
- how can I create a wireless network that appears as a single network? Do I simply use same SSID and password, or is there a better way?
- is there a way to connect wireless routers to each other... well, wirelessly? (Edit 1: I will likely need to extend the wireless signal in the apartments)

Comment: You are really getting out of the realm of home networking and into managed provider territory, so don;t be surprised that this is more than you expect or that it costs somthing non-negligible to implement. First, I recommend you put a single wifi network in each appt. that will keep the tennants from illicitly accessing each others devices. 100MbPS sounds more than a little slim for 25 residences. 3 kids with Playstations could swamp that with no effort. Either way you will have to implement some QOS or a small handful of users will ruin it it for everyone.

Comment: Yes, there are devices that can bridge/extend wireless networks. Most vendors call them "Range Extenders". Most Enterprise-grade Access Points (APs) can be aggregated into a single SSID, but you will have to consult the vendors documentation. Finally, you are goign to have to do something about management. This is too big and too centralized a deployment to avoid active management, like banning bit torrent users, implementing thresholds, etc, if you want to keep everyones netflix running smoothly.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions specifically:

- No idea - it depends on how heavily your users use the connection.  I have 3000 users on a 200mbps line at work and it doesn't struggle at all.. but if you have 3 users torrenting, they could eat your entire 100meg connection!
- Having multiple networks with the same name and password doesn't work.  Behind the scenes, the actual network name (the SSID is just a user-friendly name) will be different.  You could look at repeaters, range extenders etc to try and solve this.
- 3 - See 2.  You can use Range Extenders, Power Line Adapters, Wireless Repeaters etc to give you the desired effect.

It is probably worth consulting a local IT company as you may be better served getting a small scale corporate Wireless solution installed - especially if you are then planning to charge your users for use of your servie